# Disabling right click in appkit

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsresponder

I'm currently taking in a nextEvent within my mouseDrag function

```
    while true {
        guard let nextEvent = self.window?.nextEvent(matching: [.leftMouseDragged, .leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp]) else {
            continue
        }
        switch nextEvent.type {
        case .leftMouseDragged:
            self.cursorUpdate(with: nextEvent)
            self.mouseDragged(with: nextEvent)

        case .rightMouseUp:
            continue

        default:
            self.mouseUp(with: nextEvent)
            return
        }
    }
```

And I'm just trying to disable right click for the duration. However, with this implementation the right clicks simply queue up and get called after the loop finishes.

How would I disable right clicks being registered at all?

Comment: Where is your code executing? Can you give more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.rightMouseDown` and `.rightMouseDragged` to your matching mask. It is the `.rightMouseDown` event that makes AppKit display the context menu.

```
    guard let nextEvent = self.window?.nextEvent(matching: [.leftMouseDragged, .leftMouseUp, .rightMouseDown, .rightMouseDragged, .rightMouseUp]) else {
        continue
    }
```

You might also consider switching to `NSWindow.trackEvents(matching:timeout:mode:handler:)` instead of writing your own loop:

```
    window.trackEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDragged, .leftMouseUp, .rightMouseDown, .rightMouseDragged, .rightMouseUp], timeout: NSEvent.foreverDuration, mode: .eventTrackingRunLoopMode) { (event, outStop) in
        guard let event = event else { return }
        switch event.type {
        case .rightMouseDown, .rightMouseDragged, .rightMouseUp: return
        case .leftMouseDragged:
            self.cursorUpdate(with: event)
            self.mouseDragged(with: event)
        case .leftMouseUp:
            self.mouseUp(with: event)
            outStop.pointee = true
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Using `trackEvents` lets AppKit run the main run loop, so timers and observers can continue firing (if they are scheduled for `.eventTrackingRunLoopMode`).